# Mass update fields in Access subform

Tags: ms-access, subform

I'm trying to make an Access database where, on this form, I have textboxes named after the fields in a table. In a subform, in datasheet mode, all fields but one are inactive so I can scan in serial numbers via barcode. The other fields are supposed to be updated by an "update all" button on the parent form using the text boxes.

For background, this is to update and add to a current Excel sheet by adding the data to an Access DB. Currently in Excel, the users have a window that opens with check boxes and a select all function to selectively apply the data from text fields to the sheet.

My current code only updates the selected record.

```
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select me.trap_scan1!trap_notes,,,")
For Each fld In rst.Fields
    'print field names
    Debug.Print fld.Name
    Next
    'db.OpenRecordset("Traps", dbOpenDynaset)
    'Me.Trap_Scan1!Trap_Notes
    With rs
        .MoveFirst
        Do While Not .EOF
       ' If (Trim(![release code] & "") = "") Then
       ' .Edit
        ![release code] = Me.Trap_Notes
        .Update
  '  End If
    .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
Set rs = Nothing
```

Also tried this:

```
If Not 
IsNull(Me.Trap_Style) 
Then
    Set Me.Trap_Scan1!Trap_Style = Me.Trap_Style
    End If
```

Comment: I am thinking your `For Each` loop may not be doing what you expect it to. When you debug, what is happening?

Comment: I'm using the below for debugging:
>error:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
     msg = "error # " & Str(Err.Number) & "was generated by " _
     & Err.Source & Chr(13) & "Error Line: " & Erl & Chr(13) &      Err.Description
     MsgBox msg, , "Error"
End If
End Sub

It's saying error 3141 from DAO.Database and the select statement is using a misspelled or reserved word. Earlier it said error# 13

Comment: Sorry about the incorrect format... how should I format this better? This is my first post...

Comment: Do you know how to step through the VBA code or set a break point?

Comment: Yes, It's hitting my error code at line 5, where I'm attempting to define the record set.

Comment: Is that a new error, or?

Comment: That's what it was doing earlier, I think my code is very buggy, and don't quite know where to go. I've not done much with record sets.

Comment: No pressure, I know you all are just doing this to help... but am I barking up the wrong tree? Thanks!

Comment: I would get rid of your `For Each` loop.. Then see where you get

Comment: I commented out the "for each" lines and the "next" line, but am getting the same error (3141, select statement error) - This section of code is mostly copied from somewhere online. The code I wrote, 
'code'"If Not IsNull(Me.Trap_Style) Then
    Set Me.Trap_Scan1!Trap_Style = Me.Trap_Style
    End If" 
works, but only for one line at a time and repeated for every field. I'm not set on one way of doing this, just trying to find a way that works if you have any better ideas. Thanks!